# angular v8 - how to get production build template errors also during development mode

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular8, tsconfig, ng-build

I have the latest angular v8 installed and I want to receive basic template errors i get during production also while runing ng serve.

For example

Template

```html
<p (click)="log()">ERROR: {{ errorMessage }}</p>
```

Controller

```js
log(a){}
```

Build error

`ERROR in apps/manufacturing-tv/src/app/app.component.ts.AppComponent.html(7,9): Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.`

or

Template

```html
<p>ERROR: {{ errorMessages }}</p>
```

`ERROR in apps/manufacturing-tv/src/app/app.component.ts.AppComponent.html(7,25): Property 'errorMessages' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'. Did you mean 'errorMessage'?`

I've already tried to add the `fullTemplateTypeCheck` flag but running ng build or ng serve doesn't yield the errors.

```
{
    "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "types": ["jasmine"]
    },
    "angularCompilerOptions": {
        "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true
    },
    "include": ["**/*.ts"]
}
```

Comment: user production build by using `ng build --prod`

Comment: Hi, that does not answer my question if it is possible to get those errors in dev mode

Comment: Use `ng serve --aot` or `ng  build --aot` to enable ahead-of-time compilation

Answer (score 2):

Enable ahead-of-time compilation by calling:

```
ng serve --aot
```

or configure `aot` as the default compiler by adding it to your `angular.json`

```json
"architect": {
  "serve": {
    "options": {
      "aot": true
    }
  }
}
```

and call `ng serve`.

The same can be done for `build`.